# Disable BackButton when navigation controllers pushed via a tab bar controller

Tags: iphone

I have a naviation controller. I create a tab bar controller and add 3 sub view on to it. such that I can navigation back to the root view controller.

The problem is that since i have my navigation controllers in the tab bar format., I am not able to disable the back button.

If only one view controller is pushed on to the navigation controller, I am able to disable the back button, but when i push the tab bar controller to the navigation controllr, the back button is not disabled. I want to disable the same and add my own custom button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the navigation item on the tabBarController, rather thannon the view controller. So if you want to disable the back button from a view controller inside a tabBarController which is inside the navigationController you'd use the code:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

Comment: HI, this works. But the problem is just that the back button is hidden from all the tab and not just from the current navigation controller. How can I disable only for one tab and not all the tabs?

Comment: @user612355: In the tab you want it hidden put the above code, in the tabs you want it visible, put the above code, but change the `NO` to `YES`.

Comment: Unfortunately (as of SDK 4.3) there's a bug where, if you hide and then re-show the navigation bar, the Back button will be shown even if it's not supposed to be.  Filed.